# Is it possible to apply multiple window functions for the same column in SQL

Tags: sql, window-functions

I wonder if something like this is possible

```sql
WITH t1(day_partition, entity_id, feature) AS (values
  ('2020-05-15', 'id_1', 1),
  ('2020-05-16', 'id_1', 2),
  ('2020-05-15', 'id_2', 3),
  ('2020-05-16', 'id_2', 4) 
)

SELECT
  day_partition,
  entity_id,
  LAG(SUM(feature)) OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id order by day_partition) AS x
  -- or perhaps like this?
  --- LAG(SUM(feature) OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id order by day_partition)) OVER () AS x
FROM t1
```

This query below produces the expected results, but I wonder if the `tmp` table can be aovided

```sql
WITH t1(day_partition, entity_id, feature) AS (values
  ('2020-05-15', 'id_1', 1),
  ('2020-05-16', 'id_1', 2),
  ('2020-05-15', 'id_2', 3),
  ('2020-05-16', 'id_2', 4) 
),

tmp AS (
  SELECT
    day_partition,
    entity_id,
    SUM(feature) OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id order by day_partition) AS x
  FROM
    t1
)

SELECT
  day_partition,
  entity_id,
  LAG(x) OVER (order by day_partition)
FROM
  tmp
```

[image]

Comment: Only one `over` clause is permitted.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: What's the expected result? I fail to undertantand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to do sum and shift the summed values by one row. in this case, the x will be `null, 1, 3, 3`

Comment: I added more details, but sounds it's not possible to avoid a temporary table.

Comment: @zyxue Your query is incorrect. The `LAG()` function **requires** an `ORDER BY` clause that your query is missing. If your database accepts this, then it may be bug in the engine. By the way, what's the database?

Comment: @TheImpaler , right, I updated my quer. it's https://prestosql.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

One window function must be precomputed before the other one. The only *cosmetic* improvement you can do (if you wish) is to use a table expression in its place. If you rewrite your query this way it will look like:

```
WITH t1 (day_partition, entity_id, feature) AS (values
  ('2020-05-15', 'id_1', 1),
  ('2020-05-16', 'id_1', 2),
  ('2020-05-15', 'id_2', 3),
  ('2020-05-16', 'id_2', 4)     
)
SELECT
  day_partition,
  entity_id,
  LAG(x) OVER(ORDER BY day_partition)
FROM (
  SELECT
    day_partition,
    entity_id,
    SUM(feature) OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id order by day_partition) AS x
  FROM  t1
) y
```

But again, this query require two scopes to precompute the values before the `LAG()`.

Comment: If both window functions work on the same partition, can they be nested then? I tried, it doesn't seem to work either. Just wanna confirmation my understanding

Comment: @zyxue I think my explanation was wrong. It doesn't matter if they actually work on the same partition. The issue is one result needs to be computed first, to compute the second one.